# How to resolve Notepad++ "Writing error summary to C:\Program Files(x86)\ ...\HTMLTIDY.ERR" on Vista?

Tags: permissions, notepad++

How to resolve Notepad++ "Writing error summary to C:\Program Files(x86)\ ...\HTMLTIDY.ERR"  on Vista pc?

I have the latest version of notepad++ (just updated it two days ago).

When I try to run TextFX htmltidy, I get the above error reported by windows vista.

I've set permissions on the file htmltidy.err to allow everyone to modify/read/write/etc.

I do not understand file permissions in Win Visa.

2nd issue: I also have to click 'Allow' whenever I click to launch notepad++ even though I granted the program exe admin rights. UAC says it is an unidentified program.

Do I need to reboot to make these changes effective? What am I missing?

Comment: This looks like a permissions issue on your box.  Were you logged in as admin when you did the installation?  It appears that your grant didn't work.

Comment: This is (an OEM) laptop with Win Vista Home Premium; I believe notepad++ was installed properly. I'm not sure about being 'true' admin status when the app was installed, however.

Comment: Check which directory Notepad++ starts in. If you run it from an desktop icon (or other shortcut) then view the properties of that icon (or shortcut) and consider altering the "Start in" directory.

Answer (score 0):

**This is not an error, simply a message:**

Any errors found in the HTML codes are being written to this file.

For example:
line 1 column 1 - Warning: missing  declaration

Answer (score 0):

This is a Windows 7 restriction. Programs should not write into Program Files folder. Instead it should use a temporary folder like %TEMP% or/and %APPDATA%.

Another possible solution is to install Notepad++ outside Program Files folder, in that way you can hanle file and folder permissions by yourself.